# Функция автозагрузки на php

Tags: php

Хочу спросить про функцию автозагрузки `__autoload` на *PHP*.
 Да, я читал что функция скоро отнесется к устаревшей и знаю про альтернативные новые методы. Но, я не могу понять один вопрос, ответ на который я в интернете не нашел. В качестве значения функции `__autoload` передается `$className`. Вопрос: как и откуда она передается. 
Например. Есть папки *classes*, *lib*, *modules*, *core*, и т.д. в папке *classes* находятся классы (в соответствующих файлах) `router`, `controller_base`, `template`, `register`, `module`. Функция `__autoload` описана в файле `core`, в отдельной папке core и подключает только три класса `router`, `template`, `controller_base`.
 Почему??? И как??? Я не могу понять по какой прихоти идет именно такое подалючение когда классов больше чем три!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вызывать функцию нет необходимости,  она автоматически вызывается в момент, когда интерпретатор встречает имя еще не загруженного класса. Таким образом, будут загружены только те классы, которые реально используются.

Котеров, PHP 7, 2016, стр. 501.

Это обычная функция, если вы создаете экземпляр класса `$var = new MyClass();` автоматически вызывается функция `__autoload('MyClass')`. Чтобы перехватить ее, вы переопределяете в своем коде создавая эту функцию, например так:

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    $filename = "./". $classname .".php";
    include_once($filename);
}
```

Источник http://php.net/manual/ru/function.autoload.php

В вашем случае видимо подключаются три базовых класса по типу MVC (model, view, controller), а все остальные классы уже подключают эти базовые по мере необходимости. Как пример, зачем вам на странице контактов подключать класс каталога товаров?

Comment: Вы правы что это mvc но не моя а пример из одной из статей. Я лишь пытаюсь разобраться построчно как все работает, ибо я новичек в ооп. Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем ответ на вопрос, но не могу не написать.

Сам в свое время много мучился с поиском "идеальной" схемы автоподгрузки классов, перечитал много статей, пересмотрел много примеров, но все они были либо не очень хороши (мягко сказано) либо заточены под достаточно странные условия.

Поэтому,в целях увеличения энтропии вселенной, расскажу к чему пришел. Может быть сохранит кому день другой.

DISCLAIMER: Данное решение не претендует на звание единственно правильного. Используйте на свой страх и риск.

Пререквизиты:

1. Имена файлов-классов идентичны именам классов с суффиксом '.php'
2. Классы декларируются с использованием пространств имен
3. Пространства имен соответствуют подкаталогам, в которых лежат файлы-классы

Например у нас есть класс `AppDb` в пространстве имен `core\database`, тогда файл с этим классом будет содержать `namespace core\database;` и располагаться по пути `core/database/AppDb.php`

Функция автоподгрузки для такой структуры будет следующей:

```
const CLASS_ROOT = '/srv/www/htdocs/class/'; //"корневой" каталог для классов
spl_autoload_register(
    function ($class) {
        $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
        $file  = CLASS_ROOT . $class . '.php';
        if (is_file($file)) {
            include_once $file;
            return;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Спасибо и Вам, тоже помогли!