# Создание экземпляра класса с namespace через переменную

Tags: php, namespace

Все названия условные. Создал класс Animal, затем создал подклассы Elephant, Bird  и так далее. Функцию автозагрузки классов [взял отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602828/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php).

Папки:

```
controller.php
classes
-core
--Animal.php (namespace core)
--Bird.php (namespace core)
--Elephant.php (namespace core)
-database
```

Конфиг скрипта

```
$codes = [
    1  => 'Elephant',
    2  => 'Bird'
];
```

В контроллере изначально прописал

```
use \core\Bird as Bird;
use \core\Elephant as Elephant;
```

Затем пытаюсь создать экземпляр класса подобным образом

```
$code = 1; //поступает извне
$response = new $codes[$code]($params); // подразумеваю new Elephant()
```

Естественно выдает `Fatal error: Class 'Elephant' not found in D:\server\localhost\test\www\controller.php on line 42`, неймспейса не видит.

Получается `use` здесь вообще нет необходимости использовать, а только **генерировать вручную путь к классу с неймспейсом так?**

```
$class = 'core\\' . $codes[$code];
$response = new $class($params);
```

php документация по этому поводу http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

Comment: Jean-Claude, можете опубликовать конечный вариант?

Comment: @Виталий все то же самое, только кусочек заменен кодом ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use` - синтаксический сахар времени компиляции. В момент выполнения скрипта этих директив уже не существует. Поэтому при создании объекта из строкового имени класса `namespace` должен быть указан полным.

Для статического массива с белым списком может быть полезна такая запись:

```
$codes = [
    1  => Elephant::class,
    2  => Bird::class
];
```

Магическая константа [`::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) выполнит преобразование указанного имени класса к строке - полному имени класса с пространством имён. Это операция так же времени компиляции, поэтому директивы `use` используется, а механизм автозагрузки классов - не вызывается. Доступна начиная с PHP 5.5.

Comment: не совсем понял `::class`. Если вывести `$codes[1]` выходит тоже самое `string 'Elephant'`

Comment: Значит вы уже убрали `use` и вдобавок находитесь в глобальной области видимости. Если релевантного use нет, то `::class` воспользуется текущим пространством имён.

Comment: то есть use надо было прописать в файле конфига $codes = [] ?

Comment: да, в том файле, где вызывается константа `::class`.