# Как можно избавиться от большого свитча в PHP применяя ООП?

Tags: php, ооп

подскажите пожалуйста как в PHP в объектно-ориентированном программировании можно избавиться от такого большого свитча?

```html
    private function getImportService(string $distributorName)
    {
        switch ($distributorName) {
            case 'Дистрибьютор 1':
                return new ImportDistributor1Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 2':
                return new ImportDistributor2Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 3':
                return new ImportDistributor3Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 4':
                return new ImportDistributor4Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 5':
                return new ImportDistributor5Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 6':
                return new ImportDistributor6Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 7':
                return new ImportDistributor7Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 8':
                return new ImportDistributor8Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 9':
                return new ImportDistributor9Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 10':
                return new ImportDistributor10Service();

            case 'Дистрибьютор 11':
                return new ImportDistributor11Service();

            default:
                throw new \Exception('Not found service for select distributor');
        }
    }
```

у всех сервисов будет один метод который будет называться одинаково, но реализовываться по разному

```html
class ImportDistributor1Service
{
    public function prepare(string $dataPreparation)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607776/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private function getImportService(string $distributorName)
{
    $int = explode(" ", $distributorName)[1];
    $class = "ImportDistributor".$int."Service";
    if (class_exists($class)) {
        return new $class();
    }else{
        throw new Exception('Not found service for select distributor');   
    }
}
```

Comment: Так избавились и от свича, и от ООП одновременно )

Comment: Ну сделает человек фабрику, там такой же свитч будет. Так что этот вариант вполне.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов думал это автор скомментил. сорри)

Comment: @webDev_ да ничего, я в шутку больше =) "лайк" я честно Вам поставил =)

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов юмор я заценил изначально) только не понял сарказм ли это так как не обратил внимания на имя автора. теперь всё понятно)

Comment: да спасибо ребята!) я тоже поржал)) данный вариант уже намного лучше))